# Cycle class map in non-smooth family of projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, deformation-theory, algebraic-cycles

Let $\pi:\mathcal{X} \to T$ be a family of smooth projective complex varieties. Assume $T$ is quasi-projective, reduced, irreducible but not smooth and of positive dimension. Let $\mathcal{Z}$ be a codimension $p$ subscheme of $\mathcal{X}$ flat over $T$. Denote by $\pi': \mathcal{Z} \to T$. Under what conditions on $p$ or $\mathcal{Z}$, we can find an element $\xi \in H^{2p}(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\xi_t \in H^{2p}(\mathcal{X}_t,\mathbb{Z})$ (obtained by the pull-back morphism from $H^{2p}(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{Z})$ to $H^{2p}(\mathcal{X}_t,\mathbb{Z})$ induced by $\mathcal{X}_t \hookrightarrow \mathcal{X})$ is the class of $[\mathcal{Z}_t]$ (under the cycle class map) where $\mathcal{Z}_t:=\pi'^{-1}(t)$ for all $t \in T$?

Comment: Of course, first thing coming to one's mind is the class $[\mathcal{Z}]$. A bullet-proof sufficient condition would be the transversality of $\mathcal{Z}$ to the fibers.

Comment: @Degtyarev: The examples I have in mind it is the case. Could you please suggest some reference for this fact.

Comment: This is too obvious to give a reference. The keywords are inverse Hopf homomorphism (and Thom isomorphism) and their geometric interpretation. (Thom isomorphism should be applied to the normal bundle of the fiber.) Any **good** textbook in algebraic topology would do, but personally I learned it long ago and in Russian, so I cannot recommend any English text. (In fact, I just don't know any satisfactory English textbook :)

Comment: I mean, this is a purely topological fact. If $Z, F$ are two submanifolds transversal in $X$ and $i\colon F\to X$ is the inclusion, then $i^![Z]=[Z\cap F]$, where $i^!=D\circ i^*\circ D^{-1}$ is the inverse Hopf homomorphism (composition of the cohomological restriction and Poincare dualities).

Comment: Alex, I have difficulties to follow. Are you ware that $\mathcal{X}$ is not smooth?

Comment: @Degtyarev: $\mathcal{Z}$ need not be smooth. Can you still use Poincare duality?

Comment: If $\pi$ is smooth and $Z$ is flat over $T$ then such a class should exist, at least with complex coefficients.

Comment: For a smooth morphism $\pi$, and any flat sheaf over $T$, such as $\mathcal{O}_Z$, there will be a finite resolution by vector bundles (if $T$ is really nasty, it might exits only locally on $T$). Then at least over $\mathbb{Q}$ one can take the Chern character (alternating sum over the terms of the resolution), which agrees nicely with restriction to fibers.

Comment: I don't really see where $\chi$ smooth is relevant. For example, you could base-change using a resolution of $\chi$.